# what does this comment mean /* jshint +W040 */

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jshint

I'm going through `Angular's` source code and have found the following piece:

```
/* jshint -W040 *//* some comment here
injector.invoke(blockFns[i] || angular.noop, this);
/* jshint +W040 */
```

I know that I can use notation like `jshint -W000` to specify for jshint that the following line should not be inspected. But what is the notation with plus (`jshint +W000`) for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs:

> To re-enable a warning that has been disabled with the above snippet you can use:
>
> `/* jshint +W034 */`

http://jshint.com/docs/

So it's just to make sure it isn't ignored for the rest of file.

Comment: Ah, thank, so `jshint -W000` notation doesn't disable inspection for the one line, but for all lines following the notation?

Answer (score 1):

To re-enable a warning that has been disabled earlier.